# How to map each route in AWS API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have an app with 100+ different API routes. Examples:

- mysite.com/api/upload
- mysite.com/api/get_stuff
- my-work.com/api/get_stuff/more

Is there a way to add multiple routes easily, then having to create a method one by one for each of 100+?
I've added some, as you can see below.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

you can import APIs using **open api** or **swagger** 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-documenting-api-quick-start-import-export.html